# PHP function Math

Tags: php, function, math, echo

I have to create a PHP code calls a function with 2 numbers and displays the function return value using an echo statement. Bellow is all I have so far. Not sure where I messed up or what I need to add. Just stuck.

```
 <?php 

function myfunction( $argx = 5 , $arg4 = 4) {

return ($argx * $arg4);


}

echo ($argx * $arg4);
```

Comment: Please work through any random PHP tutorial, this isn't the place to be taught PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you made can now be used with for example

```
echo myfunction(7,8);
```

If you simply do

```
echo myfunction();
```

it will be the same as

```
echo myfunction(5,4);
```

since you've put these values as default.

Read into PHP functions, e.g.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
<?php
//            +------------------ myfunction is the function name
//            |       +---------- $argx is a parameter with the default value 5
//            |       |        +- $arg4 is a parameter with the default value 4
//            |       |        |
function myfunction($argx=5, $arg4=4) {
    return ($argx * $arg4);
}
```

Now you can call the function with `echo myfunction();`

```
echo myfunction();        // result is = 20  ! no parameters set = default (5 * 4)
echo myfunction(10, 10);  // result is = 100 ! parameters 10 and 10 = (10 * 10)
echo myfunction(10 * 10); // result is = 400 ! first parameter is 100, no seccond parameter set so default is 4 = (100 * 4)
```

[You can play with it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bccdd5ecea7cd4201385268c567efd531ea59a2)